# Android socket stream using serializable, error: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: android, sockets, nullpointerexception, serializable

I am using the Serializable for my data transmission. Below is my class impliments from Serializable.

```
public class UserAction implements Serializable{

/**
 *
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public int userID;
public transient Path path;
public transient Paint paint;

public UserAction(){
    path = new Path();
    paint = new Paint();
}

public UserAction(int ID, Path path, Paint paint){
    setUserID(ID);
    setPath(path);
    setPaint(paint);
}

public void setUserID(int ID){
    this.userID = ID;
}

public void setPath(Path path){
    this.path.set(path);
}

public void setPaint(Paint paint){
    this.paint.set(paint);
}
```

}

And the OutputStream like this:

```
 client = new Socket("localhost", 54321);
 ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
 out.writeObject(action);
 out.close();
 client.close();
```

The InputStream is:

```
 ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(client.getInputStream());
 rec_action = (UserAction) in.readObject();
 in.close();
```

But while I using the rec_action got from the inputstream. rec_action is not Null, but it's member path and paint are both NULL! get **java.lang.NullPointerException** .

Answer (score 0):

You marked those members as `transient` so serialization skips them. That is the definition of that keyword.

Comment: Thans zienkikk. But when remove the transient, it got another error:**java.io.NotSerializableException: android.graphics.Paint**.

Comment: That's because Path and Paint don't implement Serializable or Externalizable. You should read some Serialization tutorials and write your own custom routine for the task.